# Print whether a certain number is Palindromic or not in C++

Tags: c++, loops, numbers, palindrome

I have this code in my my C++ dev console that is supposed to check if a given input number is palindromic(when reversed, its still the same number). The problem is that i don't know how to iterate through the calculations to check whether its true and print the required statements

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int x) {
     int rev=0;
    //complete the function
    while(x>0){
      rev = rev*10 + x%10;
      x = x/10;
      cout<<rev<<endl;cout<<x<<endl;
      
    }
      if(x==rev){
        return true;
      }else{
       return false;
     }
   
   }

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >>n;
    
    if(isPalindrome(n)) {
        cout <<n<<" is a palindrome";
    }
    else {
        cout << n<<" is NOT a palindrome";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i input a number like 707 or 808 which are obviously palindromic, it prints the second statement that 707 is not a Palindrome number, Please help me rectify it

Comment: Does it work with 4 digit numbers (e.g. 2266 or 7007) in contrary?

Comment: Lemme try and then feedback incoming

Comment: No it doesnt, just checked now

Comment: Best you start your code in the debugger and step through line by line, this should quickly lead you to the place where your calculations exprect other values than are there.

Comment: The first loop in `iPalindrome()` modifies `x`.   The following `if` tests if `x == rev`, but that relies on `x` still holding its original value.   Store the original value of `x` in another variable, and test if *that* is equal to `rev`.

Comment: Okay working on it

Comment: I stored x in another variable and am still getting the same inaccurate result, perhaps you could check the loop for me

Comment: The loop is fine, as far as it goes.   Your following of advice given is questionable.

Comment: Okay let me try that suggestion

Comment: Being a palindrome is a property of **text**. Convert the number to text, and check whether the text is a palindrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are destroying the original input x in while loop.
Simply copy it in a temporary variable, and it should fix your code. like

```
bool isPalindrome(int x) {
    int rev=0;
    int tmp = x;
    while(tmp>0){
      rev = rev*10 + tmp%10;
      tmp = tmp/10;
      
    }
    return (x== rev);
}
```

Comment: I have echoed x out and its true that while modified the value to iterate for the rest of the logic, so am assigning x to a new variable, work with that variable in the loop and do comparisons with my new variable, pretty smart

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
bool isPalindrome(string);
int main(){

    int n;
    cout<<"Enter a number: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    string ntoString=to_string(n);//here I converted the number to string

    if(isPalindrome(ntoString))
        cout<<n<<" is palindrome"<<endl;
    else cout<<n<<" is not palindrome"<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

bool isPalindrome(string firstString){

    for(int i=0;i<firstString.length();i++){
        if(firstString[i]!=firstString[firstString.length()-1-i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: A slightly more effective version would be to just search to the middle of the string:
`bool isPalindrome(string firstString){ return std::equal(firstString.begin(), firstString.begin() + firstString.size()/2, firstString.rbegin()); }`